# ¿Como mostrar una matriz sin usar el java.util.Arrays?

Tags: java, array, arraylist, matrices

Tengo el siguiente código el cual me lee los caracteres de un archivo y me los almacena en una matriz String, pero al momento de mostrar la matriz solo me la muestra usando la función `arrays`.

```
public static void lectura(){

    System.out.println("Ingrese la ruta");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ruta = sc.next();

    String dato;
    String[][] myArray = new String[6][5];

    try {
        File archivo = new File(ruta);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(archivo);
        int row = 0;
        String[] info;
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            dato = myReader.nextLine();
            info = dato.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                myArray[row][i] = info[i];
            }
            row++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));//************************
    
}
```

Como se observa en la linea que comente con asteriscos, dicha linea me muestra la matriz, pero habrá alguna manera de mostrar dicha matriz sin usar la función `arrays`, intente con los típicos ciclos for anidados

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++){
            System.out.print(myArray[j][k]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

pero solo me tira un error que no entiendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se puede mostrar con tu ciclo, pero tienes un error en el límite superior de la iteración sobre la variable `k`, debiera ser `myArray[j].length` y no solo `myArray.length`. Es por esa razón que, al tratar de iterar sobre un elemento que no existe, salta la excepción que estás viendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese error sale porque esta mal la condición del segundo ciclo, estas usando el `.length` en ambos ciclos y eso esta mal. Recuerda que la matriz no existe como tal en java, cuando declaras `array[][]` estas diciendo que vas a crear un array o vector que contiene otro array dentro. En tu código, tu matriz es de 6x5 donde j toma el valor de 6 y k el valor de 5, `myArray.length` te va a devolver el valor del Array contenedor, que en este caso vale 6, cuando el programa intente recorrer la posición `[0][5]` va a saltar esa excepción porque k no tiene 6 posiciones.

La forma correcta de recorrer una matriz es la siguiente:

```
for(int i=0; i<unArray.length; i++)
        {//                        *Observa que aqui llamo al length de la posicion[i]
            for(int j=0; j<unArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                //código con la lógica
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción para imprimir un array que esta dimensionado como :

```
  String[][] myArray = new String[6][5];
```

Que contiene como ejemplo estos datos:

```
[[a, s, d, f, a], [a, d, f, s, d], [a, f, d, f, d], [d, f, s, a, f], [s, f, d, a, f], [a, f, d, s, f]]
```

se realizaría de esta forma:

```
  int renglones = 6;
  int columnas = 5;
  for (int j = 0; j < renglones; j++){ 
      for (int k = 0; k < columnas; k++){ 
          System.out.print(myArray[j][k]+" "); 
      } 
      System.out.println(""); 
  }
```

de esta forma obtendrias como salida, de acuerdo a los datos de ejemplo:

```
a s d f a 
a d f s d 
a f d f d 
a f s a f 
s f d a f 
a f d s f
```